# Android Studio not downloading sdk

Tags: android

my android studio starts downloading the android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip file upon opening, so i don't even know where should i put this file so that android studio will pick it. Please help me to where to put this file.

Comment: I'd like to prevail upon reviewers to leave this question open. Stack Overflow is not only for programming questions, but also for questions regarding programming tools, of which Android Studio is one.

Answer (score 1):

These are your SDK tools, which are required to develop and test apps.

Just download the zip. Then extract it wherever you want. Then, when you open Android Studio, it'll ask for SDK Tools directory. Just point it to where you extracted your zip file.